# Error while creating new data file in HP-Exstream

Tags: hp-exstream

I am trying to create a data file for my application with XML as input and map it to my HP Exstream variables. But when I am trying to save the file it is giving me error "No customer-level tag specified! Engine will not process.". I am not sure how to resolve this error. There is no customer level information I want in my input. Can anyone explain what is this error and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What HP Exstream is telling you is that you have not defined a tag that will allow Exstream to know when a customer begins and ends. This does not have to be a tag that says `<customer-level>`, but rather the tag you are using in the XML to determine where a customer begins and ends.

When you are using an XML file as input, you may be dealing with multiple customers take this for example:

```
<item>
   <address>
      <line>a</line>
      <line>b</line>
   </address>
   <body>Hello World</body>
</item>
<item>
   <address>
      <line>c</line>
      <line>d</line>
   </address>
   <body>Hello Universe</body>
</item>
```

I would be using the `<item>` tag to tell HP Exstream where my customer begins and ends.

You can choose the customer tag in the properties of the tags.

Comment: Thanks so much. This was really helpful.